# Absolute position click potion of zoomed image in android

Tags: android, canvas

I want to calculate the un-scaled absolute position of the image drawn on the canvas based on the position clicked by the user on the scaled canvas.

I used following zoom implementation
[Translate/scale bitmap within boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961223/translate-scale-bitmap-within-boundaries)

So far,

```
public boolean inMe(int x, int y, Region ClickRegion) {
    if(mScaleFactor == 0) 
                mScaleFactor = 1;

            float curX = ((x*1.0f)/ mScaleFactor) - (mPosX * mScaleFactor);
            float curY = ((y*1.0f) / mScaleFactor) - (mPosY * mScaleFactor);

            x = (int)curX;
            y = (int)curY;

            //ClickRegion is a grapics.Region computed on non-zoomed coordinates
            if (ClickRegion.contains(x, y))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
}
```

This works fine, when there is no zooming, but when its zoomed there are significant issues.

**EDIT**

This is the algo I used for zooming and panning.

```
    public class PanZoomView extends View {

    public static final String TAG = PanZoomView.class.getName();

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private float viewHeight;
    private float viewWidth;
    float canvasWidth, canvasHeight;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private float minScaleFactor;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX, mLastTouchY;

    private boolean firstDraw = true;

    private boolean panEnabled = true;
    private boolean zoomEnabled = true;

    public PanZoomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public PanZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    public PanZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        bitmap = bmp;
        resetZoom();
        resetPan();
        firstDraw = true;
        invalidate();
    }

    public Bitmap getImageBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return getImageBitmap();
    }

    public void resetZoom() {
        mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    }

    public void resetPan() {
        mPosX = 0f;
        mPosY = 0f;
    }

    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap());
    }

    public BitmapDrawable getImageDrawable() {
        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), bitmap);
        return bd;
    }

    public BitmapDrawable getDrawable() {
        return getImageDrawable();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//      Log.v(TAG, "onDraw()");

        if (bitmap == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "nothing to draw - bitmap is null");
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        if (firstDraw 
                && (bitmap.getHeight() > 0) 
                && (bitmap.getWidth() > 0)) {
            //Don't let the user zoom out so much that the image is smaller
            //than its containing frame
            float minXScaleFactor = (float) viewWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
            float minYScaleFactor = (float) viewHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
            minScaleFactor = Math.max(minXScaleFactor, minYScaleFactor);
            Log.d(TAG, "minScaleFactor: " + minScaleFactor);
            mScaleFactor = minScaleFactor; //start out "zoomed out" all the way

            mPosX = mPosY = 0;
            firstDraw = false;

        }
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(mScaleFactor, minScaleFactor);

        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
//      Log.d(TAG, "canvas density: " + canvas.getDensity() + " bitmap density: " + bitmap.getDensity());

//      Log.d(TAG, "mScaleFactor: " + mScaleFactor);

        //Save the canvas without translating (panning) or scaling (zooming)
        //After each change, restore to this state, instead of compounding
        //changes upon changes
        canvas.save();
        int maxX, minX, maxY, minY;
        //Regardless of the screen density (HDPI, MDPI) or the scale factor, 
        //The image always consists of bitmap width divided by 2 pixels. If an image
        //is 200 pixels wide and you scroll right 100 pixels, you just scrolled the image
        //off the screen to the left.
        minX = (int) (((viewWidth / mScaleFactor) - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2);
        maxX = 0;
        //How far can we move the image vertically without having a gap between image and frame?
        minY = (int) (((viewHeight / mScaleFactor) - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2);
        maxY = 0;
        Log.d(TAG, "minX: " + minX + " maxX: " + maxX + " minY: " + minY + " maxY: " + maxY);
        //Do not go beyond the boundaries of the image
        if (mPosX > maxX) {
            mPosX = maxX;
        }
        if (mPosX < minX) {
            mPosX = minX;
        }
        if (mPosY > maxY) {
            mPosY = maxY;
        }
        if (mPosY < minY) {
            mPosY = minY;
        }

//      Log.d(TAG, "view width: " + viewWidth + " view height: "
//              + viewHeight);
//      Log.d(TAG, "bitmap width: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " height: " + bitmap.getHeight());
//      Log.d(TAG, "translating mPosX: " + mPosX + " mPosY: " + mPosY);

//      Log.d(TAG, "zooming to scale factor of " + mScaleFactor);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

//      Log.d(TAG, "panning to " + mPosX + "," + mPosY); 
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mPosX, mPosY, null);
        canvas.restore(); //clear translation/scaling
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        if (zoomEnabled) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        if (panEnabled) {
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                    // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                    if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                        float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                        float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                        //Adjust for zoom factor. Otherwise, the user's finger moving 10 pixels
                        //at 200% zoom causes the image to slide 20 pixels instead of perfectly
                        //following the user's touch
                        dx /= (mScaleFactor * 2);
                        dy /= (mScaleFactor * 2);

                        mPosX += dx;
                        mPosY += dy;

                        Log.v(TAG, "moving by " + dx + "," + dy + " mScaleFactor: " + mScaleFactor);

                        invalidate();
                    }

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;

                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                    final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                    final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                        // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                        // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                        final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                        mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                        mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
//          Log.d(TAG, "detector scale factor: " + detector.getScaleFactor() + " mscalefactor: " + mScaleFactor);

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Currently zoomEnabled/panEnabled can only be set programmatically, not in XML

    public boolean isPanEnabled() {
        return panEnabled;
    }

    public void setPanEnabled(boolean panEnabled) {
        this.panEnabled = panEnabled;
    }

    public boolean isZoomEnabled() {
        return zoomEnabled;
    }

    public void setZoomEnabled(boolean zoomEnabled) {
        this.zoomEnabled = zoomEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Calls getCroppedBitmap(int outputWidth, int outputHeight) without
     * scaling the resulting bitmap to any specific size.
     * @return
     */
    public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap() {
        return getCroppedBitmap(0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Takes the section of the bitmap visible in its View object
     * and exports that to a Bitmap object, taking into account both
     * the translation (panning) and zoom (scaling).
     * WARNING: run this in a separate thread, not on the UI thread!
     * If you specify that a 200x200 image should have an outputWidth
     * of 400 and an outputHeight of 50, the image will be squished
     * and stretched to those dimensions.
     * @param outputWidth desired width of output Bitmap in pixels
     * @param outputHeight desired height of output Bitmap in pixels
     * @return the visible portion of the image in the PanZoomImageView
     */
    public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(int outputWidth, int outputHeight) {
        int origX = -1 * (int) mPosX * 2;
        int origY = -1 * (int) mPosY * 2;
        int width = (int) (viewWidth / mScaleFactor);
        int height = (int) (viewHeight / mScaleFactor);
        Log.e(TAG, "origX: " + origX + " origY: " + origY + " width: " + width + " height: " + height + " outputWidth: " + outputWidth + " outputHeight: " + outputHeight + "getLayoutParams().width: " + getLayoutParams().width + " getLayoutParams().height: " + getLayoutParams().height);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, origX, origY, width, height);

        if (outputWidth > 0 && outputWidth > 0) {
            //Use the exact dimensions given--chance this won't match the aspect ratio
            b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, outputWidth, outputHeight, true);
        }

        return b;
    }

      @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            viewHeight = h;
            viewWidth = w;
        }
}
```

Comment: instead on Canvas.scale/Canvas.translate use Canvas.drawBitmap with a Matrix parameter,  that Matrix can be used to map points/rect/radius etc

Comment: Are you scaling around a pivot point? Is that what mPosX/Y is? Also, could you clarify what you're trying to do a bit more? You're looking for the pixel the user clicked on on a scaled image?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I a create image with objects, where user can select this object and drag. In an unzoomed canvas the above algo works fine, however when zoomed its miss aligned so the objects will not be detected even when the user touches on it. I have added the algo I used for zooming and panning. x,y are user touch points.  mPosX and mPosY are panning offset (see algo).

Comment: again: use Matrix and its mapping methods

Comment: Can you please give me an example, not sure what you mean.

Comment: use Canvas#drawBitmap() with a Matrix parameter and then you can map whatever using Matrix#map*() methods

Comment: I tried out as I understood your comment. It did not do what I want. Please see the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all comment, but this worked for me.

```
public boolean inMe(int x, int y, Region ClickRegion) {


    float curX = ((x*1.0f)) + (-1*mPosX * 2* mScaleFactor);
    float curY = ((y*1.0f)) + (-1*mPosY * 2* mScaleFactor);

    x = (int)((curX/ mScaleFactor));
    y = (int)((curY/ mScaleFactor));

    if (cluster.ClickRegion.contains(x, y))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```